# How can i scrape img src with select in python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I can't extract image src's. The class in the code is the class of the img tag. I got a KeyError when I tried to use another tag's class. How can i get the src of the image?

```
from base64 import decode
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import csv
from time import sleep
from random import randint
import numpy as np

headers = dict()
headers[
    "User-Agent"
] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"
images = []
titles = []
authors = []
pages = np.arange(1, 2, 1)
for page in pages:
    url = "https://www.dr.com.tr/kategori/Kitap/Cocuk-ve-Genclik/grupno=00884?Page=" + str(page)
    results = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")
    book_div = soup.find_all("div", class_="prd-main-wrapper")
    sleep(randint(2, 10))
    for bookSection in book_div:
        all_imgs = [img["src"] for img in soup.select(".lazyloaded")]
        images.append(all_imgs)
        print(all_imgs)

        name = bookSection.find("a", class_="prd-name").get('title')
        titles.append(name)

        author = bookSection.find("div", class_="prd-row").text.strip()
        authors.append(author)
        
  
books = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Image": images,
        "Book": titles,
        "Author": authors,
    }
)
books.to_csv("dr_child.csv", index=False, header=True,encoding = 'utf-8-sig')
```

As a result, only this [] returns.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to extract src from img tag and add this data to dataframe using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73023714/how-to-extract-src-from-img-tag-and-add-this-data-to-dataframe-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

```py
import httpx
import pandas as pd
import trio
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:102.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/102.0'
}


async def get_soup(content):
    return BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml', parse_only=SoupStrainer('div', class_='prd-main-wrapper'))

allin = []


async def worker(rec):
    async with rec:
        async for client, page in rec:
            print(f'Extracting Page# {page}')
            params = {
                'Page': page
            }
            while True:
                try:
                    r = await client.get('grupno=00884', params=params)
                    if r.is_success:
                        break
                except httpx.RequestError:
                    continue
            soup = await get_soup(r.content)
            allin.extend([
                (
                    x.select_one('div.prd-row a').get_text(strip=True),
                    x.select_one('a.prd-name')['title'],
                    x.select_one('img')['data-src']
                )
                for x in soup.select('div.prd-main-wrapper')])


async def main():
    async with httpx.AsyncClient(timeout=10, headers=headers, base_url='https://www.dr.com.tr/kategori/Kitap/Cocuk-ve-Genclik/') as client, trio.open_nursery() as nurse:
        sender, receiver = trio.open_memory_channel(0)
        async with receiver:
            for _ in range(10):
                nurse.start_soon(worker, receiver.clone())

            async with sender:
                for page in range(1, 3):
                    await sender.send([client, page])
    df = pd.DataFrame(allin, columns=['Title', 'Name', 'Image'])
    print(df)
    # df.to_csv('data.csv',index=False,encoding='utf-8-sig')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    trio.run(main)
```

Output:

```
Extracting Page# 1
Extracting Page# 2
                    Title  ...                                              Image
0          Stephanie Moss  ...  https://i.dr.com.tr/cache/154x170-0/originals/...   
1            Nikola Bozic  ...  https://i.dr.com.tr/cache/154x170-0/originals/...   
2           Ferenc Molnar  ...  https://i.dr.com.tr/cache/154x170-0/originals/...   
3         Liane Schneider  ...  https://i.dr.com.tr/cache/154x170-0/originals/...   
4    Helen Stratton Would  ...  https://i.dr.com.tr/cache/154x170-0/originals/...   
..                    ...  ...                                                ...   
85  Constanze Von Kitzing  ...  https://i.dr.com.tr/cache/154x170-0/originals/...   
86       Aziz Sivaslıoğlu  ...  https://i.dr.com.tr/cache/154x170-0/originals/...   
87          J. K. Rowling  ...  https://i.dr.com.tr/cache/154x170-0/originals/...   
88         Susanna Tamaro  ...  https://i.dr.com.tr/cache/154x170-0/originals/...   
89            Sinan Yaşar  ...  https://i.dr.com.tr/cache/154x170-0/originals/...   

[90 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: I honestly doubt that the OP wants all those bells and whittles of `async` when a simple change is all there is to it.

Comment: @baduker variety of answers is usually open the door for new methods even if the context is simple.

Comment: Yeah, true, but what you're essentially doing here is just throwing loads of advanced code at the OP without even explaining why you're rewriting the whole thing in the first place. Also, this doesn't really answer the question how to use `select` to get the image source.

Comment: it's good that this site has no protection, otherwise we would get a block or captcha by changing the number of pages more than 50

Comment: There are less complex ways to async this... why such complexity?

Comment: @SergeyK if the site were having a protection so I was going to provide different answers but since the cross origin headers showing the full scenario so there’s no blocks can occurs

Comment: @platipus_on_fire_333 I don’t use low level such as asyncio ! I’m a big fan of high level in first place and in same time I care about the efficiency of large event loop instead of closed circle of main loop

Answer (score 0):

Just change this line:

```
all_imgs = [img["src"] for img in soup.select(".lazyloaded")]
```

To this line:

```
all_imgs = [img["data-src"] for img in soup.select(".prd img")]
```

Sample code:

```py
from random import randint
from time import sleep

import numpy as np
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

images = []
titles = []
authors = []
pages = np.arange(1, 2, 1)
for page in pages:
    url = "https://www.dr.com.tr/kategori/Kitap/Cocuk-ve-Genclik/grupno=00884?Page=" + str(page)
    results = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")
    book_div = soup.find_all("div", class_="prd-main-wrapper")
    sleep(randint(2, 10))
    for bookSection in book_div:
        all_imgs = [img["data-src"] for img in soup.select(".prd img")]
        print(all_imgs)
        images.append(all_imgs)
```

Should produce this:

```
['https://i.dr.com.tr/cache/154x170-0/originals/0001985154001-1.jpg', 'https://i.dr.com.tr/cache/154x170-0/originals/0001853072001-1.jpg', 'https://i.dr.com.tr/cache/154x170-0/originals/0001904383001-1.jpg', 'https://i.dr.com.tr/cache/154x170-0/originals/0001925655001-1.jpg', 'https://i.dr.com.tr/cache/154x170-0/originals/0001979322001-1.jpg', 'https://i.dr.com.tr/cache/154x170-0/originals/0001988553001-1.jpg', 'https://i.dr.com.tr/cache/154x170-0/originals/0001849713001-1.jpg', 'https://i.dr.com.tr/cache/154x170-0/originals/0001870527001-1.jpg', 'https://i.dr.com.tr/cache/154x170-0/originals/0001851768001-1.jpg', 'https://i.dr.com.tr/cache/154x170-0/originals/0000000148380-1.jpg',

and more ...
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me.

Comment: @platipus_on_fire_333 check the code now.

Comment: Now it works. Somehow yours pulls different images than mine. 'Lazy' imgs seems to reside on a different server/cdn (bkmkitap.com)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed now this is a different site than your previous question.

This will get all the images from a page:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:102.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/102.0'
}

r = requests.get('https://www.dr.com.tr/kategori/Kitap/Cocuk-ve-Genclik/grupno=00884?Page=1')
soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")
all_imgs = [img.get('data-src') for img in soup.select('img.lazy')]
print(all_imgs)
```

Result:

```
['https://cdn.bkmkitap.com/cok-bekledim-seni-yaz-tatili-kral-sakir-11-11384602-72-K.jpg', 'https://cdn.bkmkitap.com/dragon-ball-1-ve-2-9437721-50-K.jpg', 'https://cdn.bkmkitap.com/lo-10742711-71-K.jpg', 'https://cdn.bkmkitap.com/gunesi-uyandiralim-358512-11575004-35-K.jpg', 'https://cdn.bkmkitap.com/monster-cilt-2-11691276-71-K.jpg', 'https://cdn.bkmkitap.com/haikyu-4-9464025-44-K.jpg',...]
```